# Accessing CoreWindow from a windows phone 8.1 runtime component

Tags: c#, c++, silverlight, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps

I'm trying to access the CoreWindow from a windows phone 8.1 C++ runtime component. The component needs to react to some events fired by CoreWindow. I have the following code.

```
IAsyncAction^ MyClass::RegisterCoreWindowVisibilityChanged()
{
    return CoreApplication::MainView->CoreWindow->Dispatcher->RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority::High,
        ref new DispatchedHandler(
        [this]
        {
            auto eventHandler = ref new TypedEventHandler<CoreWindow^, VisibilityChangedEventArgs^>(this, &MyClass::OnCoreWindowVisibilityChanged);
            Window::Current->CoreWindow->VisibilityChanged += eventHandler;
        }
    ));
}
```

This works fine, when the application using the component is a universal app, but fails in a silverlight application with an access violation exception.

```
0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000000.
```

Apparently `Windows::Current` returns null in a silverlight app. Is there a way to do it so that it works in silverlight as well as a windows store app?

Comment: Not related directly to the problem, but why are you attaching to an event using the dispatcher?

Comment: Windows::Current->CoreWindow can only be accessed from the UI thread I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That object is only available in a Universal application (as [documented](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.window.aspx)).

You would need to either conditionalize your compile or consider switching to a universal app for both desktop and phone.

Comment: The component is meant to be used in several applications which may or may not be universal apps. How would I conditionalize the code to work with Silverlight? I couldn't find anything equivalent to VisibilityChanged.

Comment: What are you specifically trying to accomplish? Maybe there's a way to handle it in a different way.

Comment: The runtime component is a service which needs to deactivate certain parts when the app goes to the background and reactivate when it comes back to the foreground. Instead of having to always program this functionality to any app using the component, I wish to handle setting it up automatically in the component itself.

Comment: None of the app activation lifecycle events meet your needs?

Comment: Aren't the app activation lifecycle events in the PhoneApplicationService class? Is there a way to use it from a windows runtime component?